# ¿Cómo extraer los números de una cantidad de dígitos en especifico con expresiones regulares?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Deseo obtener números con una dimensión de 6 y 7 dígitos. Esto fue lo que avancé pero solo extrae 7 dígitos.

```
df['Prueba1']= df['Descripción'].str.extract('(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)',expand = True)
```

Obtengo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es si se puede optimizar el código para poder extraer los números con dimensión de dígito del 6 al 7.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes optimizar muchísimo:

```
[0-9]{6,7}
```

Esta expresión regular atrapa los números con entre 6 y 7 dígitos.

- `[0-9]` atrapa todos los posibles dígitos de un número
- `{6,7}` cuantifica 6 y 7, atrapa cadenas de 6 o 7 dígitos.

Lo que está en los corchetes (`{x}`) puedes ser cualquier número o serie de números, sirve para especificar las veces que se tiene que repetir la regla anterior.

Pienso que esto es más fácil que escapar dígito por la cantidad de dígitos en el número buscado. Es hasta más fácil de leer.